# Swing : Transparent border's radio button when focus

Tags: java, swing, border, jradiobutton

I get stuck at remove border of radio button when i click on it ?
can I do it ?
thank in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer is :

```
rdbStaff.setFocusPainted(false);
```